# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar el error " MySQL shutdown unexpectedly" en XAMPP Control Panelv3.3.0?

Tags: xampp

Este problema se me produjo al momento de volver a acceder a MySQL de "xampp", pensé que era un típico error de compatibilidad con la aplicación "laragon" pero no fue el caso; al toparme con este error lo primero que fui a hacer es buscar por internet posibles soluciones, aunque algunos si les funciono en mi caso no fue así, aunque halla hecho todo lo que investigue.
vi algunos videos y el que me mas se acerco a la solución fue el siguiente: primer video que seguí(deje tal cual como esta después de realizar el segundo video).

[1]: https://youtu.be/5cCT1ThLqqU `data1 = posible_solucion;`
[2]: https://youtu.be/ipMedkjMupw `data2 = posible_solucion-talvez;`

no se si después de eso tuvo algo que ver con que solucionara mi error. pero lo que lo soluciono fue **al momento de cambiar de puerto, te vas a config hacia abajo te toparas con lo siguiente:
port: 3306, en si son dos puertos que hay que cambiar por lo siguiente puerto: port: 30337.**

en conclusión no se si realmente solucione el error aun sigo viendo si continua asi normalmente o tarde o temprano sucederá otra vez; y si solamente debí haber presionado "services" y ver cual era error en segundo en vez de desperdiciar tiempo en hallar la solución pero ni modos, solo espero que les sirva de algo

Comment: Deberías ir a la fuente del error y consultar el registro del servidor MySQL para conocer el motivo por el que el servidor MySQL se detiene tras intentar arrancarlo. Es muy probable que sea un error en los cambios de configuración que has hecho, pero es necesario asegurarse. ¿Podrías mirar el contenido del archivo `mysqld.log`?

Comment: Acabo de leer lo que solucionaste cambiando el puerto del servidor MySQL de XAMPP. Que sepas que si eso ha solucionado el problema es porque tienes dos servidores MySQL instalados y el segundo en arrancar cae porque el primero ya ha ocupado de manera exclusiva el puerto `3306`. Deberás arreglar esto porque al servidor al que te estás conectando no es el que instaló XAMPP, si no el otro que hacía colisionar el puerto. Al del XAMPP solo podrás conectarte si indicas explícitamente en el código el puerto `30337` a la hora de conectarte a él.